# AngularJS Flickr API 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, flickr

I'm trying to get public photos from Flickr using AngularJS and getting this console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Here's my code:

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ng', 'ngResource']);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  });
```

Here's my Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vB9BJDh6B8DtSFlod1F2?p=preview

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url of the flickr API you are using returns *XML*.

Add `format=json` in the request url. Also, replace `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` with `jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK`.

To sum up, query like that:

```
$http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

See **[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xK9oqlWObtrDpxPFYb7B?p=preview)**